# How to close Apache Flink REST API on the version of 1.10.2

Tags: apache-flink

Apache Flink 1.10.2 has  CVE-2020-17518 vulnerability in the REST API. Now that I want to turn off the REST API service, how should I set up the configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Flink 1.10.3 [was released](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-Apache-Flink-1-10-3-released-td41097.html). This release includes the fix for CVE-2020-17518. You can get the newly released binaries from Apache [Flink's download page](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#apache-flink-1103).

---

Out-dated response:

Unfortunately, you cannot disable this feature through the configuration file as it is used to upload the jar to the Flink cluster.

You have multiple options now:

1. You update to one of the supported versions [1.11.3](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#apache-flink-1113) or [1.12.0](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#apache-flink-1120) that have the fix already included.
2. You apply the fix [a5264a6](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/a5264a6f41524afe8ceadf1d8ddc8c80f323ebc4) to the Flink 1.10.2 sources and build Flink yourself using {mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfast} as described in [Building Flink from Source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/flinkDev/building.html#build-flink). A symlink {build-target/} will be created after the Maven call succeeds. This symlink points to the newly compiled binaries.
3. You watch the [Flink mailing list thread](http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/DISCUSS-Releasing-Apache-Flink-1-10-3-td47784.html) on creating a release 1.10.3. There are plans, currently, to include a backport of the bugfix. [FLINK-20875](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20875) is covering the backport.

I hope that helped.

Best,
Matthias